# What is the difference between evangelizing and proselytizing?

Tags: evangelism, conversion, preaching, proselytizing

Aren't they both focused on converting people? What's the difference?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is question for the dictionary. See [proselytize](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/proselytize) and [evangelize](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/evangelize?s=t).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## [Evangelism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evangelism) is Christian [proselytizing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proselytism)

To proselytize means to attempt to convert a person from one religion to another. To evangelize means to proselytize *for* Christianity.

Answer (score -2):

**What is the difference between evangelizing and proselytizing?**

Gospel = euaggelion = good news

Evangelist = euaggelistēs = one who heralds or proclaims the good news

Proselytize is not in the Bible. Proselytizing exceeds the definition of proclaim by going into the realm of salesmanship and even coercion.